# IntelliJ IDEA override $user

Tags: intellij-idea, velocity, vtl

It's a quite simple question, but I can't find an answer to it using SO-Search and Google.

Is it possible to override the default `$user` VTL-variable used in file-templates globally, instead of setting it in each template with `#set($user = "...")` ?

Like some sort of setup-script for IntelliJ itself, where I can alter the value?

Thanks in advance.

By the way, I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate 12.1.6.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34475894/907576 there I propose to vote up Jetbrains bug-tracker issue "Configure custom author name/email/organization to be used in file templates, completion etc"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to modify the IntelliJ's `.vmoptions` file(s) in a text editor.

- In Windows, edit `IntelliJ-Install-Location/bin/idea.exe.vmoptions` and/or `IntelliJ-Install-Location/bin/idea64.exe.vmoptions`.
- In Mac OS X, edit `IntelliJ-Install-App.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions`.

Within these files simply add or modify the following line:

```
-Duser.name=Your name
```

If you recognize this syntax, that's because Intellij IDEA uses the Java System Property `user.name` to fill `$user` and `${USER}`.

Comment: You can actually do this from inside intelliJ. This link describes it for android studio http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration. Probably IDEA has the same

Comment: Editing that file only works if you haven't used the application yet. If you have, then you need to edit the one at "%USERPROFILE%\.IdeaIC2016.2\idea.exe.vmoptions" (adjust for IDEA version). Obviously, I'm talking about the Windows version.