# Change ${USER} environment variable in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, environment-variables, javadoc, author

Intellij IDEA has class/file templates like this:

```
/**
 * Created by ${USER} on ${DATE}.
 */
```

where `${USER}` by default is logged in user name (or licensed user name for Ultimate versions).

I need to have name in file templates different from logged in OS user name. How can I change in IDEA this variable?

What I can, but this it not what i'm looking for:

- Change template header directly. NO, I need to change variable for all templates and other usages in the IDE.
- start IDEA from bat/cmd/lnk whatever with changed `%USERNAME%` OS environment variable. NO, I'm looking for solution in IDEA settings, not runtime settings.
- changing `idea.exe.vmoptions` (`idea64.exe.vmoptions`) like described [in this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19620291/907576) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18738394/907576) answers may be a good solution, but has some disadvantages (applies changes system wide, requires admin privileges).

So, the main idea: is it possible in IDEA to set variable values in local user settings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA override $user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618669/intellij-idea-override-user)

Answer (score 1):

So, finally on Jetbrains bug tracker i found [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145370), and apparently no fix for it is planned. If you are interested in some solution - **vote for the feature request**.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy.

In IdealC2020,you can click menu `Help-> Edit Custom VM Options`.

you should append a line:

```
-Duser.name=authorNameX
```

then you restart IDEA , it works.